# Verify password contains letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#password').val().indexOf(/[a-z]/) != -1)
```

Does this work? if so is there something wrong with it because its not working.

Comment: Are we talking regex here or just checking that whatever password contains letter A or B etc?

Comment: just to see if the password contains a letter in it so that its not all numbers. have everything working but the letters, giving me an issue.

Comment: Note that that is case sensitive, so you are checking for lower case, unaccented letters only.

Comment: If you only want numbers then validate only numbers not letters. because you have to take care of capital letters [A-Z] as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your check like the following because you want to work with an object supporting regular expression syntax:

```
var valContainsLetter = /[a-z]/i.test($('#password').val())
```

The `i` flag is to support lower and upper case letters by the way.

Comment: this way still will return true if i put a 1

Comment: It does return `true` but only if the password does also contain a letter. This is since you asked to check for a letter and not to check for letters only.

Comment: General note: When using regular expressions to check for letters be aware that JavaScript's regular expressions unfortunately see character classes only in the context of ASCII. Thus if your letters include characters like `üäßŋĸł` you should get a library's support. See [Steven Levithan's blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode) for further information.

Answer (score 5):

The [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method accepts a *string*, not a *regular expression*.

If you want to test a regular expression then use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: $('#password').val().match(/[a-z]/))     this works but it takes numbers!

Comment: That checks if it contains "a letter", it doesn't check that it contains "only letters".

Comment: no i mean if i put on the check returns true, sorry for the late resp.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not work because you have to use `match()` function for that.

I also recommend that if you want only numbers then you should try to validate only numbers.

Do not allow anything else except number.

```
if( $('#password').val().match(/[0-9]+/) ){
    // Contains only numbers from 0-9
}
```

Comment: i was numbers and letters, just not only numbers or only letters. my issue right now is that it returns true when i put 1 for example.